# Upgraded to Python 2.7.10 and now SSL deployment broken

Tags: python

So I'm having a ton of SSL errors, and I found out it's due to `2.7.10`. The other developer can deploy fine because he is on `2.7.6`.

I installed Python 2.7.6 using the Mac installer here: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/

Then I went to my `usr/bin/python` and renamed it to `python_2_7_10` (Hack I was informed to use)

[image]

And now when I do `python -v` I see that I am switched to 2.7.6

[image]

However now when I run my fab deploy script
 `alias d_dash_dev="fab deploy_dashboard_to_dev"` I get this error:

```
➜  tickers git:(master) ✗ d_dash_dev
zsh: /usr/local/bin/fab: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

Anyone else having this problem?

Here, I tried to update my fab with `sudo pip install --force fab`

Then got the following error:
`sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

Now I tried then to figure out what's wrong with pip...

Here are my console:

```
➜  ~  /usr/local/bin/pip
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~  /usr/local/bin/pip
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~  /usr/local/bin/pip2
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip2: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~  /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip2.7: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~  which python
/usr/local/bin/python
➜  ~  which python_2_7_10
/usr/bin/python_2_7_10
```

My .zshrc

```
export ZSH=/Users/leongaban1/.oh-my-zsh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin"
export PATH="/usr/bin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

Comment: Renaming it back to `python` is probably the simplest fix. Arrange your `PATH` so that `/use/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` (should trivially be the case, but wasn't always on Mac OSX).

Comment: Renaming a Python executable to mimic another version is kind of a dirty hack. No surprise you get side effects...

Comment: @tripleee I added my zshrc file export contents, would you mind a look?

Comment: You only need to `export` once (or even zero times, as `PATH` is almost certainly already exported by system scripts). All but the last assignment is overwriting previous assignments. And you end up with `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`. Sorry to say this, but pretty messy.

Comment: Ok the problem is my env upgraded itself to 2.7.10 because of an Apple update. I need to change to using a Virtual Env until they patch 2.7.10 to fix the SSL problem. However my Fab is configured to point to 2.7.10, so it's going to be a pain in the ass trying to redirect that to 2.7.6 or 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most recent update (2.7.10) broke a lot of SSL infrastructure by porting all the SSL shit from Python 3.3 instead of doing a couple of small changes.

https://lwn.net/Articles/640318/

Because I clicked update during a Mac update I'm screwed now, until they fix this issue and patch it with `2.7.11` or something.

Only other option for me is to install a VirtualEnv and use `2.6` (I'll have to figure that out later)

So warning to anyone out there dealing with SSL, don't do the Mac upgrade that happened this week.